# Не получается достать поле(URLFIeld) модели связанной через ForeignKey в сериализаторе

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Есть две модели и два сериализатора. Один сериализатор наследует другой сериализатор, но данные наследуемого сериализатора выводит не все, точнее не выводит только поле с ссылкой. Что мне надо сделать, чтобы в quyeryset оно по итогу мне вывело ссылку?
Вот код:
models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(unique=True)
    lang_course = models.CharField(default="Ru", choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class Video(models.Model):
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='course')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    video_link = models.URLField(max_length = 150, unique=True, blank=True)
    lang_video = models.CharField(default='Ru', choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # video_link = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        exclude=['course_id']
        # fields = '__all__'


class CourseDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    videos = VideoSerializer(source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'lang_course', 'videos')
```

И вот на всякий случай views.py

```
class CourseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    # queryset = Video.objects.all()
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseDetailSerializer
```

Comment: а что выводит и какой ожидаемый результат?

Comment: AttributeError at /api-auth/videocourses/course_detail/1/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `video_name` on serializer `VideoSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Course` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Course' object has no attribute 'video_name'.
Вот ошибка, которая появляется, я сейчас немного поменял модельку, т.к. имена совпадали

Comment: А получить я хочу queryset со всеми данными обеих моделей за раз. Точнее объекта видео и принадлежащего видео курс. Сейчас у меня ошибки, поэтому свой получаемый queryset показать не могу.

Comment: Раньше получал ошибку Original exception was: 'Course' object has not attribute 'course_id'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Переименуйте поле `course_id`  в `course` - так будет правильнее, так как по этому полю вы получаете конкретно объект, а не ID.
2. `related_name` стоит исправить на `related_name="videos"`.

Далее нужно исправить сам сериализатор, а именно

```
class CourseDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    videos = VideoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'lang_course', 'videos')
```

Так же вот ссылка на [офф. документацию](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

Comment: Правильно. Я не переименовывал course_id и разобрался в своей проблеме чуть раньше ответа. Но спасибо, все же пожалуй я переименую course_id в course